# How can I override a JavaScript variable when page is visible again?

Tags: javascript

When visiting a web page I want to declare a start time and send an AJAX request when the user leaves the site. It works like expected but when changing the tab or minimizing the browser the start time remains the same as when the user accessed the web page. I thought I could override the start time by declaring it within a function which is fired when the tab is active again but with no success.

Here is my code so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var starts = Math.ceil(Date.now() / 1000);
    
    //declare new start time when user returns
    document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function() {
        if(!document.hidden) {
            var starts = Math.ceil(Date.now() / 1000);
        }
    });

    //AJAX
    //value of old starts is used here instead of new declared starts
    ...
});
```

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: you redeclared a new `starts` variable. the rest of the function has already run - so you'll have to extract that logic out

Comment: You'll have to decide what events to act on. If you use window resize, you'll probably have to set some maximum dimensions so your timer doesn't reset due to small window size changes, for example. So, your question isn't entirely clear since you haven't laid out your expectations very specifically.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I just want to reset the start timer when a tab is active again, so when the users returned to the tab. When minimizing it in a smaller window it shouldn't reset the timer but when minimizing the browser, it should.

Comment: @DanielA.White Maybe I have some understanding issue here but the redeclaration should happen when the user reenters a tab. Isn't this the case when the user returns to the tab since the first declaration of starts happend when calling the page the first time?

Answer (score 0):

Try `document.visibilityState === 'visible'` so your code will look like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var starts = Math.ceil(Date.now() / 1000);
    
    //declare new start time when user returns
    document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function() {
        if(document.visibilityState === 'visible') {
            var starts = Math.ceil(Date.now() / 1000);
        }
    });
});
```

Read more about it here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/visibilitychange_event

Comment: I tested your code but it doesn't change the variable issue. Still got the old starts value in my calls.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const timer = document.querySelector("#timer");

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  startTimer(); // starttime on load
});
let intervalID = null;
let timerValue = 0;
const startTimer = () => {
  intervalID = setInterval(() => {
    timerValue++;
    timer.innerText = timerValue;
  }, 1000);
}

const stopTimer = () => {
  clearInterval(intervalID);
}

document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', () => {
  if (document.hidden) { // codition for browser tabs is active or minimize
    stopTimer(); // stop timer when you leave tab minimize it on
    return;
  }
  startTimer(); // start timer when you comback to tab maximize it
})
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>time spend in seconds:<span id="timer">0</span>
    <h2>
</div>
```

Comment: you got a typo .... "retun"

Comment: I wish we could have typo suggestions in StackOverflow as well :)]